# Unable to parse DateTime from SQL using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

I am relatively new to C# and any suggestions to the query below i will greatly appreciate.

I've gone through a lot of articles here but none of the solutions seems to work in my case

Im reading DATETIME from sql and passing it to a string

```
dateStart = rd1["DATE_START"].ToString();
```

when debugging in VS it's showing date time in a format i like:     **22/11/2015 17:12:45** 
But Label is showing **11/22/2015 5:12:45 PM**

When i use the code to ParseExact

```
dtime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", provider);
```

No matter what i use for the format i always get

> [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]

```
DateTime dtime;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
provider = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
dateStart = rd1["DATE_START"].ToString();
dtime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", provider);
LBDateOpened.Text = dtime.ToString();
```

I'm lost, please help.

Comment: Did you try not specifying the culture ?

Comment: Are you sure your query isn't returning an actual `DATETIME` type? If that were the case, you could just `(DateTime)rd1["DATE_START"]`, which is significantly better than parsing it yourself.

Comment: The format string in `ParseExact` doesn't look, well, exact to the source string.

Comment: Thank you @CoryNelson. Your suggestion worked!   dtime=    (DateTime)rd1["DATE_START"];
 LBDateOpened.Text = dtime.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 2):

Following should work fine...

```
var dateStart = (DateTime)rd1["DATE_START"]; // assign DateTime
var dateString = dateStart.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); // format to string
```